# How to load an specific activity (multiple intent) on filter ListView- Item-Click?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

There no error, but when i click a item of listview nothing happen. I have more than 10 items. and go to difference activities. Any idea? I'am beginner in eclipse also java.

Example:
1.Niat (ListView-OnItemClickListener) will go to NiatActivity.class
2.Lafaz (ListView-OnItemClickListener) will go to LafazActivity.class

Here my code. Thanks in advance.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainTwoActivity extends Activity {

    // List view
    private ListView lv;

    // Listview Adapter
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    // Search EditText
    EditText inputSearch;

    // ArrayList for Listview
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_two);

        // Listview Data
        final String products[] = { "Niat",
                "Lafaz", "Solat" };

        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);

        inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);

        // Adding items to listview
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item,
                R.id.product_name, products);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

        /**
         * Enabling Search Filter
         * */

        inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2,
                    int arg3) {
                // When user changed the Text
                MainTwoActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,
                    int arg2, int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

        });

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // if(position == 1)
                String openClass = adapter.getItem(position);
                if (openClass.equals("Niat")) {
                    // code specific to first list item
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(),
                            NiatActivity.class);
                    startActivity(myIntent);
                }

                else if (openClass.equals("Lafaz")) {
                    Intent myIntent1 = new Intent(view.getContext(),
                LafazActivity.class);
                    startActivity(myIntent1);

                }
            }

        });

    }
}
```

Comment: use java reflection http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/dynamic-class-loading-reloading.html

Comment: If you wanna go to different activities on list item click just use Switch statement for its position.

Comment: @PiyushGupta already switch statement but still not working

Comment: U want to open muliple activities on list item click?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Reflection is better but also u can use of Hashmap
**Use OF HashMap**

```
  HashMap<String, Class>hashMap=new HashMap<String, Class>();


  hashMap.put("Niat",NiatActivity.class);
  hashMap.put("Lafaz",LafazActivity.class);
  hashMap.put("Solat",SolatActivity.class);
   lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
   String openClass = adapter.getItem(position);
   Intent myIntent1 = new Intent(MainTwoActivity.this,
              hashMap.get(openClass));
            startActivity(myIntent1);
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

MaWhen starting a new activity you should use

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainTwoActivity.this ,NiatActivity.class);
```

View getContext() doesnt carry the full context of your app. Read up [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14658469/android-intent-context-confusing)