# The Intent constructors parameters

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent

The Intent class had 6 constructors

> **Intent()**
>
> Create an empty intent.

---

> **Intent(Intent o)**
>
> Copy constructor.

---

> **Intent(String action)**
>
> Create an intent with a given action.

---

> **Intent(String action, Uri uri)**
>
> Create an intent with a given action and for a given data url.

---

> **Intent(Context packageContext, Class cls)**
>
> Create an intent for a specific component.

---

> **Intent(String action, Uri uri, Context packageContext, Class cls)**
>
> Create an intent for a specific component with a specified action and
>   data.

I'm almost new in android programming and mostly using the fifth one when i need to start another `Activity` or `Fragment`:

```
Intent(Context packageContext, Class<?> cls)
```

When i want to start an `Activity` from a `Fragment` i do this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), DestinationActivity.class);
```

as far as i know, `getActivity()` will return an `Activity`

But the constructor expect a `Context`, how is this possible???

is it possible because of that the `Activity` that had returned by `getActivity()` implicitly invoke `getApplicationContext()`???

Comment: Look in the API Docs how Context is inerhited. You can travel the back to context from activity or application or fragment. Any of these are also contexts ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a look at the argument `Context` very closely in the fifth Intent declaration. It reflects polymorphism. The `Intent` takes a `Context` argument so you can pass any object that is a `Context` or derives from the `Context` class.

Activity, AppCompatActivity, IntentService, Service all derive from the `Context` class and hence can be passed as an argument to the method.

Answer (score 6):

> Activity inherits context. Thus, if you are in an activity, you only need to pass itself to use the context. It also contains a pointer to getBaseContext(). You might occasionally need to reference that, if you need the entire application context, but most likely you won't for a while.

You can find more details about the Activity class [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html).

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14658469/android-intent-context-confusing) about the intent constructor parameters is similar to yours and has a really good answer. I think you'd like to check it out.

Hope it helps.

Comment: the link that you provided is my own question (this question)

Comment: @hamid_c Sorry! I had mixed them up. Fixed it! :)

Answer (score 1):

Activity extends Context so you can just cast it:

```
Intent i = new Intent((Context)getActivity(), DestinationActivity.class);
```

Comment: a@Marcin Orlowski. I hope you can fix my problem. I'm creating an intent specific to a component. I'm getting a wavy red line below the second paramater which is my service class name in the following code.        Intent wifi_intent = new Intent(Application.Context,WifiMonitoringService.class);  Its says "; expected " error when I place the mouse over that.  Please help me out. I have posted that question. You can find it in the following link      http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40828123/couldnt-pass-the-service-class-to-the-intent-constructor-intentcontext-class