# What can use as the first argument for the context?

Tags: android, android-context

Here is my code for a TimePicker class I have created

picker.java

```
package com.example.abhijeet.todo;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.app.TimePickerDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.format.DateFormat;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TimePicker;

import java.util.Calendar;

/**
 * Created by Abhijeet on 9/6/2017.
 */

public class Picker extends DialogFragment implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Use the current time as the default values for the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        // Create a new instance of TimePickerDialog and return it
        return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, minute,
                DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
    }



    @Override
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int i, int i1) {
        //Creating a View object because this class do not extend from activity class so no findviewbyid() method is present
       View v =View.inflate(*  ?   *,R.layout.activity_editor,null);  //HERE
        //Displaying the user selected time on the Edit Text view
        EditText edittime = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.time_editext_field);


    }
}
```

I am trying to show the time selected via the picker in a edit text box.
I am not able to find the right context for the argument.

I have read the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14658469/android-intent-context-confusing) which explains about the different usages of the context, but that does not seem to help me.

Thank for the help in Advance.

Comment: create constructor for Picker class having Context parameter

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help but I'm afraid I've tried that already. It says " Avoid non-default constructors in fragments: use a default constructor plus Fragment#setArguments(Bundle)" Does it makes sense to you  @BapusahebShinde

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just call [getContext()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getContext())

As [DialogFragment](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html) is child of [Fragment](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html). So all the Fragment class method could be called in DialogFragment.

Like this

```
@Override
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int i, int i1) {
        //Creating a View object because this class do not extend from activity class so no findviewbyid() method is present
       View v =View.inflate(getContext() ,R.layout.activity_editor,null);  //HERE
        //Displaying the user selected time on the Edit Text view
        EditText edittime = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.time_editext_field);
    }
```

You can also call [getActivity()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getActivity()) method. If you are targeting to older API than 23:

```
@Override
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int i, int i1) {
        //Creating a View object because this class do not extend from activity class so no findviewbyid() method is present
       View v =View.inflate(getActivity() ,R.layout.activity_editor,null);  //HERE
        //Displaying the user selected time on the Edit Text view
        EditText edittime = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.time_editext_field);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you It works but shows a warning " Call requires API level 23 (current min is 21)". How can i make it supported on lower API devices while still maintaining this implementation ?

Comment: Wow, I have been struck at this for about an hour or so. I did try to read the documentation, what is the correct procedure for searching issues like this as i am quite sure this won't be the last and I am likely to get banned once again from asking questions  Meh.

Comment: you should use appcompat fragments, then you could use getContext everywhere

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you are used. `Activity` -> `getApplicationContext()`, `Fragment` -> `getActivity()`, `Adapter`  -> `getContext()`