# What's the difference for creating an Intent with context between getApplicationContext() or activity

Tags: android

We always create an Intent with context

```
Intent intent = Intent(context, SomeClass.class)
```

I can use this(activity) or getActivity(fragment) as context, in some situations I can use getApplicationContext.

My question is what't the difference for Intent under there two circumstances?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14658478/527808

Answer (score 0):

getApplicationContext() is giving application context but context is giving current activity context.I hope its help you.

Comment: But for that Intent?

Comment: you can use onActivityResult() for R&D